# want to convert class component into functional component it has two render method so i am confused how to convert it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Chart from "./Chart";
import { getData } from "./utils";

import { TypeChooser } from "react-stockcharts/lib/helper";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react/cjs/react.production.min";

class ChartComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        getData().then(data => {
            this.setState({ data })
        })
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state == null) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
        return (
            <TypeChooser>`enter code here`
                {type => <Chart type={type} data={this.state.data} />}
            </TypeChooser>
        )
    }
}

render(
    <ChartComponent />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

the above mention i want to convert the class component into functional component i tried but its not running may be it has two render method
the above code is from index.js file
now the below mentioned code is Chart.js which is imported in index.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { scaleTime } from "d3-scale";
import { utcDay } from "d3-time";

import { ChartCanvas, Chart } from "react-stockcharts";
import { CandlestickSeries } from "react-stockcharts/lib/series";
import { XAxis, YAxis } from "react-stockcharts/lib/axes";
import { fitWidth } from "react-stockcharts/lib/helper";
import { last, timeIntervalBarWidth } from "react-stockcharts/lib/utils";

class CandleStickChart extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { type, width, data, ratio } = this.props;
        console.log("type===>",type);
        const xAccessor = d => d.date;
        const xExtents = [
            xAccessor(last(data)),
            xAccessor(data[data.length - 100])
        ];
        return (
            <ChartCanvas height={400}
                    ratio={ratio}
                    width={width}
                    margin={{ left: 50, right: 50, top: 10, bottom: 30 }}
                    type={type}
                    seriesName="MSFT"
                    data={data}
                    xAccessor={xAccessor}
                    xScale={scaleTime()}
                    xExtents={xExtents}>

                <Chart id={1} yExtents={d => [d.high, d.low]}>
                    <XAxis axisAt="bottom" orient="bottom" ticks={6}/>
                    <YAxis axisAt="left" orient="left" ticks={5} />
                    <CandlestickSeries width={timeIntervalBarWidth(utcDay)}/>
                </Chart>
            </ChartCanvas>
        );
    }
}

CandleStickChart.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    ratio: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(["svg", "hybrid"]).isRequired,
};

CandleStickChart.defaultProps = {
    type: "svg",
};
CandleStickChart = fitWidth(CandleStickChart);

export default CandleStickChart;
```

Now i want to convert these two files in functional base

Comment: I am unable to see `type` variable, where is it. please console errors.

Comment: the commponent is not running so it is not showing any error, not a hello rendering a hello message

Comment: `document.getElementById("root");` is useless here. The component that imports this component needs to define it. And yes, `type` is not defined.

Comment: i am editing my question with both compoenent i think i miss one compoenet thanks and sorry for this

Comment: kindly check Andy and sanat Gupta

Comment: where you are rendering your app can you show us your App.js

Comment: basically this is a library react stock charts, it has no app.js file i clone it example in class it running perfectly but not in functional

Comment: CandleStickChart.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    ratio: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(["svg", "hybrid"]).isRequired,
};

i also want to know what is this?

Comment: it's difficult to find out can you create sandbox for that

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2/tree/master/examples/CandleStickChart
sand box link sanat and Andy

Comment: Sanat and Andy any positive answer?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please replace your code with this I believe you will get your result..

https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-violet-octymg?file=/src/index.js

Thanks

```
const ChartComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then((data) => {
      setData(data);
    });
  }, []);

  if (data == null) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <TypeChooser>
      {(type) => <Chart type={type} data={data} />}
    </TypeChooser>
  );
};

render(<ChartComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: and what about second component ?

Comment: have a look sandbox URL there is no error. maybe you need to update your react version

Comment: you can easily convert like this.

Comment: thankyou so much it is running kindly tell me about main chart component

Comment: In chart.js these below part confusing me
CandleStickChart.propTypes = {
 data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
 width: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
 ratio: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
 type: PropTypes.oneOf(["svg", "hybrid"]).isRequired,
};

CandleStickChart.defaultProps = {
 type: "svg",
};
CandleStickChart = fitWidth(CandleStickChart);

export default CandleStickChart;

Comment: it's propTypes validation i think you need to learn about prototype validation... when you are calling that component then you need to pass these variables because it's required.

Comment: is it same in functional component?

Comment: CandleStickChart = fitWidth(CandleStickChart); 
i also dont get this line

Comment: The name is different... too be honest  I am not aware of this plugin

Comment: I got the proptypes , could you please do my chart.js component into functional compoenent?

Comment: because when i change my component to functional my ompoenent gives error at this line